# Zend_Auth and profile edit

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth

After logging user in I make some operations on his account. After that I want to update his data held bu Zend_Auth. How can I update all data at once, and not one by one which I know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Read the data from Auth_Storage, update it and save it back.